# Round Corner of Path Line SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

How can I make a line with the ends rounded? I'm drawing a simple straight line as follows, but cannot get the ends round. ".cornerRadius" doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
struct Line: View {
    let geoProx: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {
        Path{ path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: geoProx.size.width/2, y: geoProx.size.height/2))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geoProx.size.width/2 - geoProx.size.width/4, y: geoProx.size.height/2))

        }
        .stroke(lineWidth: 8.0)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
        .zIndex(1.5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try replacing:

```swift
.stroke(lineWidth: 8.0)
```

with:

```swift
.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8.0, lineCap: .round))
```

Comment: I'm using swift 5, this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
.stroke(.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
```